# Python paste columns of a pandas data frame, one of them contains'@' in every row

Tags: python, pandas

I built the pandas data frame df:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13000 entries, 0 to 12999    
Data columns (total 4 columns):    
at            1625 non-null object    
screenName    1625 non-null object
espacio       1625 non-null object    
promo         1625 non-null object    
dtypes: object(4)    
memory usage: 406.3+ KB

df['at'].describe()
count     1625
unique       1
top          @
freq      1625
Name: at, dtype: object
```

I am trying to create a new column that pastes all the strings of each column by row:

```
df["tweet"] = df.at+df.screenName+df.espacio+df.promo
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_AtIndexer' and 'str'
```

I think that is because all column df['at'] is filed with "@", because when I leave that column out of the code it works. How can I solve this?

Comment: `.at` is an indexer. You also have a column with that name. You need to access that column using brackets `df['at']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["tweet"] = df.at.astype(str)+df.screenName+df.espacio+df.promo
```